# tomcat8 Maven plugin

Tags: maven-plugin, tomcat8

Is anyone having idea on status of tomcat8 Maven Plugin. Is it ready for use or not ? I can locate the repository for it [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.maven/tomcat8-maven-plugin/3.0-r1756463])  but could not find this plugin on apache [site](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin.html). I tried using it with same configuration as that of tomcat7-maven-plugin but it does not start my application.

Answer (score 1):

Go to following link 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.maven/tomcat8-maven-plugin/3.0-r1756463

copy paste the dependency tag

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0-r1756463</version>
```

**But still if your pom file shows can't locate repository** 
click on the download link in above url and download jar file and past it in `<your-home-directory>/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/maven/tomcat8-maven-plugin/3.0-r1756463`

In your IDE update maven project

Answer (score 0):

tomcat maven plugin is only available for tomcat7, you can try spring boot which has an embedded tomcat8, it also provides other containers, like jetty